# Substitute values from file1 to file2 awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, xml

I have an input file in xml *FILE1* :

```
 <Sector sectorNumber="1">
    <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
    <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
    <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
  </Sector>
  <Sector sectorNumber="2">
    <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
    <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
    <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
  </Sector>
  <Sector sectorNumber="3">
    <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
    <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
    <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
  </Sector>
```

and another *FILE2*:

```
Cell11="42921"
Cell12="42925"
Cell13="42928"
Cell21="42922"
Cell22="42926"
Cell23="42929"
Cell31="42923"
Cell32="42927"
Cell33="42920"
```

where I want to substitute values from *FILE2* to *FILE1*, so it should look like :

```
<Sector sectorNumber="1">
        <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42921" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42925" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42928" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
      <Sector sectorNumber="2">
        <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42922" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42926" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42929" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
      <Sector sectorNumber="3">
        <Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42923" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42927" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
        <Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42920" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
```

So basically, all the values are inserted in `cellIdentity=""` in order, as it is in *FILE2*.
I have this awk code :

```
awk 'FNR==NR{FS="=";a[NR]=$2;next}/cell/{c++;FS=OFS;$4="cellIdentity="a[c];}1' FILE2 FILE1
```

but I get this :

```
<Sector sectorNumber="1">
        <Cell cellNumber "1" cellCreated "YES" cellIdentity cellIdentity= "35000" numberOfTxBranches "1" hsCodeResourceId "0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42925" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42928" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
      <Sector sectorNumber="2">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42922" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42926" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42929" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
      </Sector>
      <Sector sectorNumber="3">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42923" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42927" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42920" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
</Sector>
```

The problem is only in the first row, but it's not good. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Your idea is brilliant but better use a suitable utility for XML file such as xmlstarlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you read first line contains `/cell/` in `FILE2`, `FS` still set to `=`.

A simple solution is using `split` when reading `FILE1`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{split($0,array,"=");a[NR]=array[2];next}/cell/{FS=OFS;$4="cellIdentity="a[++c];}1' FILE2 FILE1
<Sector sectorNumber="1">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42921" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42925" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42928" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
  </Sector>
  <Sector sectorNumber="2">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42922" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42926" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42929" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
  </Sector>
  <Sector sectorNumber="3">
<Cell cellNumber="1" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42923" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="2" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42927" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
<Cell cellNumber="3" cellCreated="YES" cellIdentity="42920" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0"/>
  </Sector>
```

And you don't have to use `c++`, you can try `a[++c]` directly.